# Javascript function execution synchronization

Tags: javascript, function, synchronization

I have three javascript files 1.js, 2.js, 3.js

## 1.js

```
function getOne()
{
return "one";
}
```

## 2.js

```
function getTwo()
{
return "two";
}
```

## 3.js

```
getOne(function(resp1)
{
console.log(resp1)
getTwo(function(resp2)
{
console.log(resp2);
}

});
```

The function calls in 3.js are not executed at all. I load the js files in the order 
1.js
2.js
3.js

COuld someone please help

Comment: `getOne` doesn't take parameters. How can you possibly expect your callbacks you're passing into them to be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work, as already mentioned, is that your methods don't handle the callbacks you pass in as arguments.

To make it work like you want you need to rewrite your methods to look like this:

```
function getOne(callback)
{
  callback("one");
}

function getTwo(callback)
{
  callback("two");
}
```

Since you question is about function execution synchronization however, you might wish to go down another path.

What you are doing will work fine for a couple of functions, but when you get to the point where you wish to synchronize many functions you end up with the [pyramid of doom](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/) where code marches to the right faster than it marches forward.

```
step1(function (value1) {
    step2(value1, function(value2) {
        step3(value2, function(value3) {
            step4(value3, function(value4) {
                ...continue ad nauseum 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In that case you might want to look into [futures and promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)

You can read more about promise patterns in javascript here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
getOne(function(resp1)
   {
      console.log(resp1)
      getTwo(function(resp2)
      {
         console.log(resp2);
      }
   }
);
```

Does in fact call `getOne`, however it passes in an anonymous function as a parameter.  `getOne` doesn't actually *take* any parameters (though passing one doesn't hurt, nor cause any errors), nor is that anonymous function actually *executed* anywhere.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I'd start by giving `getOne` a parameter:

```
function getOne(fnFoo)
{
   return "one";
}
```

You'd then be able to call the function you pass in:

```
function getOne(fnFoo)
{
   fnFoo();
   return "one";
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, though maybe I missed the gist of what the code was attempting to do.